# How to calculate multi class dice coefficient for multiclass image segmentation?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am trying to train a network for multiclass segmentation and I want to use dice coefficient (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient)) as loss function instead of cross entropy.

You can have a look at the formula [here](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?dice%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B2*A%5Ccap%20B%7D%7B%7CA%7C+%7CB%7C%7D) (where *S* is segmentation and *G* is ground truth.)

One naive simple solution is to take an average of the *dice* coefficient of each class and use that for loss function. This approach would not differentiate between classes with larger area against the classes with smaller number of pixels (voxels).

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one class, and these are categorical with no ordinal relationships, e.x. we don't imply `dog` being smaller than `cat` only because we have set labels `1` and `2` respectively, you should be already working with one-hot encoded labels. As so, you are perfectly fine to calculate Dice coefficient, using function below,

```
import numpy as np

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, epsilon=1e-6):
"""Altered Sorensen–Dice coefficient with epsilon for smoothing."""
    y_true_flatten = np.asarray(y_true).astype(np.bool)
    y_pred_flatten = np.asarray(y_pred).astype(np.bool)

    if not np.sum(y_true_flatten) + np.sum(y_pred_flatten):
        return 1.0

    return (2. * np.sum(y_true_flatten * y_pred_flatten)) /\
           (np.sum(y_true_flatten) + np.sum(y_pred_flatten) + epsilon)
```

The extra bit here is, we get `1` if both predicted and true labels are empty.